# I got TimeoutError when sending mails with SMTP using Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, smtp, smtplib

I'm using Python3.7 and I got the following error when I run my code:

TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

here's my code:

```
import smtplib
from email import encoders
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 25)
server.connect("smtp.gmail.com",465)

server.ehlo()

with open('password.txt', 'r') as f:
   password = f.read()

server.login('mymail@gmail.com', password)

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = 'mymail@gmail.com'
msg['To'] = 'mymail2@yahoo.com'
msg['Subject'] = 'Mail testing with Python'

with open('message.txt', 'r') as f:
    message = f.read()

msg.attach(MIMEText(message, 'plain'))

text = msg.as_string()
server.sendmail('mymail@gmail.com', 'mymail2@yahoo.com', text)
```

what seems to be the problem? is there any mistake in my code or is it just my network connection?

Comment: Try using port 587 in smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)

Comment: @Karthik I tried the 587 port but I got the same error, Karthik

Comment: Could you provide transcript of SMTP session? [`server.set_debuglevel(1)`]  `SMTP` protocol is human readable.

Comment: @AnFi hi, AnFi, I have already solved my code, thanks for the feedback! I forgot to enable the less secure apps for my Gmail :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, for gmail to work properly with python script, you need to configure gmail to allow low security apps. I assume you have already done that part, otherwise you can check on gmail help.

[Gmail help on turn on less secure app](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en)

This is the script that should send your email:

```py
import smtplib

from email.mime.text import MIMEText

from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)

server.ehlo()

server.login('mymail@gmail.com', "your password")


msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative',)
msg['From'] = 'mymail@gmail.com'
msg['To'] = 'mymail2@yahoo.com'
msg['Subject'] = 'Mail testing with Python'

with open('message.txt', 'r') as f:
    message = f.read()

msg.attach(MIMEText(message, 'plain'))

text = msg.as_string().encode('utf8')

server.sendmail('mymail@gmail.com', 'mymail2@yahoo.com', text)
```

Comment: Hi, Fusion, thanks for the feedback. I ran the code but now I got:
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted.
I'm sure the password and the email are correct, idk why this happened